# How can I include/exclude certain controllers from a DispatcherServlet

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a `DispatcherServlet` which by default uses a `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` to find all controllers with `@RequestMapping` annotations.

This works fine, except that it picks up all controllers in my spring context, but I only want it to expose certain controllers.

Is there any way of doing this that doesn't involve extending a bunch of spring classes?

(Unfortunately my spring context has to contain these additional controllers as they also provide some functionality that I need to call using java, and I'm not able to split these up currently)

Answer (score 0):

You can configure include/exclude filters to customize classpath scanning. This can be done both in XML Spring config or Java based `@Configuration`. So depending on how many `@Controller` annotated classes you need to exclude, you can either list them under `assignable` or use `regex` filter. See Spring docs section "Using filters to customize scanning" for details, e.g. for [Spring 3.2](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-scanning-filters).

Comment: see the last part of my question in brackets - I need these classes to be spring beans because they provide other functionality, I just don't want them to be exposed as controllers.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry, missed that part. Then I don't think it is doable without overriding some of Spring classes. One trick you could probably do is to implement [HandlerInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) and in `preHandle()` method deny access to URLs that belong to `@Controller` classes you want to exclude.